# how to find the parametric equation for linear motion

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble finding the parametric equation of linear motion. The problem ask: Give parametric equation for 12 inch diameter (6-inch radius) vinyl record that is rotating on a turntable at 33.3 revolutions per minute in the counter-clockwise direction.

I think that this is the equation: 6 cos ((2pi/33.3)t), 6 sin ((2pi/33.3+),

The second part of the problems ask: As the record rotates, an ant walks from its center along in a straight line along a radius towards the edge of the record at a constant speed of 18 inches per minute. Give parametric equations of the motion of the ant (the combined linear and rotational equation).

I know I have to use my answer from part A, but I don't understand how to find the parametric equation for the linear motion.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The motion of the ant:

$x,y =  r(t) \cos (\frac {2\pi}{33.3} t), r(t) \sin (\frac {2\pi}{33.3} t)$

where $r(t)$ is the distance that the ant is from the spindle of the record player.

$x,y =  (18 t)\cos (\frac {2\pi}{33.3} t), (18 t)\sin (\frac {2\pi}{33.3} t)$